# Request-response processor in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Please help me to find a correct way to approach this task in Haskell.

Suppose, we want to write a simple server loop that will receive commands (requests) serialized in some way (as Strings, for simplicity of question), execute them and return serialized response back.

Let's start with data types that will contain request/response information:

```
data GetSomeStatsRequest = GetSomeStatsRequest
data GetSomeStatsResponse = GetSomeStatsResponse
    { worktime :: Int, cpuavg :: Int }

data DeleteImportantFileRequest = DeleteImportantFileRequest
    { filename :: String }
data DeleteImportantFileResponse = FileDeleted
                                 | CantDeleteTooImportant

data CalcSumOfNumbersRequest = CalcSumOfNumbersRequest Int Int
data CalcSumOfNumbersResponse = CalcSumOfNumbersResponse Int
```

Actual number of request types can be very large (hundreds) and has to be constantly maintained. Ideally we want requests independent from each other and organized into different modules. Because of that, joining them in one datatype (`data Request = RequestA Int | RequestB String | ...`) is not very practical. Same for responses.

But we are sure, that every request type has a unique response type, and we want to enforce this knowledge on compilation level. Class types with functional deps give us just that, am I right?

```
class Response b => Request a b | a -> b where
    processRequest :: a -> IO b
class Response b where
    serializeResponse :: b -> String

instance Request GetSomeStatsRequest GetSomeStatsResponse where
    processRequest req = return $ GetSomeStatsResponse 33 42
instance Response GetSomeStatsResponse where
    serializeResponse (GetSomeStatsResponse wt ca) =
        show wt ++ ", " ++ show ca

instance Request DeleteImportantFileRequest
                 DeleteImportantFileResponse where
    processRequest _ = return FileDeleted -- just pretending!
instance Response DeleteImportantFileResponse where
    serializeResponse FileDeleted = "done!"
    serializeResponse CantDeleteTooImportant = "nope!"

instance Request CalcSumOfNumbersRequest CalcSumOfNumbersResponse where
    processRequest (CalcSumOfNumbersRequest a b) =
        return $ CalcSumOfNumbersResponse (a + b)
instance Response CalcSumOfNumbersResponse where
    serializeResponse (CalcSumOfNumbersResponse r) = show r
```

Now, for the part that is tricky for me: main loop of our server... I imagine it should look somewhat like this (working with stdin/stdout for simplicity):

```
main :: IO ()
main = forever $ do
    putStrLn "Please enter your command!"
    cmdstr <- getLine
    let req = deserializeAnyRequest cmdstr
    resp <- processRequest req
    putStrLn $ "Result: " ++ (serializeResponse resp)
```

and function to deserialize any request:

```
deserializeAnyRequest :: Request a b => String -> a
deserializeAnyRequest str
    | head ws == "stats" = GetSomeStatsRequest
    | head ws == "delete" = DeleteImportantFileRequest (ws!!1)
    | head ws == "sum" = CalcSumOfNumbersRequest (read $ ws!!1) (read $ ws!!2)
    where ws = words str
```

Obviously, this fails to compile with `Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘CalcSumOfNumbersRequest’`. And even if I would be able to create decodeAnyRequest function with this type signature, compiler will get confused in `main` function, because it will not know the actual type of `req` value (only typeclass restriction).

I understand, that my approach to this task is completely wrong. **What is the best practical way to write request-response processor of this kind in Haskell?**

Here is a Gist with example code combined:  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3ef9a0d0bd039b23c669

Comment: there are several ways - either you put all your commands into a ADT and have `deserializeAnyRequest :: String -> MyCommand` or you write `tryDeserializeSpecificRequest :: String -> Maybe SpecificCommand` and then *try* them one by one till you get a `Some foundCommand`...

Comment: Yep, basically, both methods are almost the same as @danidiaz suggestion, and right now, I'm thinking that this is the only possible approach... I don't like it because of code duplication and no compile-time checking of request-response types...

Comment: you get compile-time checking with the first - ofc. the actual parsing will always be runtime-checked ... obviously

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't understand... So there will be `data Request = ReqA | ReqB` and `data Response = RespA Int | RespB String`, right? And functions `deserializeAnyRequest :: String -> Request` and `processAnyRequest :: Request -> IO Response`, correct? Now, what if someone on the project will use it like this: `(RespB str) <- processAnyRequest ReqA`... How it will be compile-time checked?

Comment: well obviously you would feed it into a function that can handle all different `Response` types instead (and it will be checked - the compiler will warn you about the partial case)

Comment: No I mean, that `processAnyRequest ReqA` will return value `RespA 123` and it will be pattern-matched against `RespB String`, which will fail during run-time. Same example: `data Request = GiveMeNumber | GiveMeString`, `data Response = HereIsNumber Int | HereIsString String`, and now we call: `(HereIsString str) <- processAnyRequest GiveMeNumber`...

Comment: As a note, if you really wanted to ensure a 1-1 connection between request and response types, you'd use a functional dependency like `... | a -> b, b -> a`

Comment: @DerekElkins I guess I could imagine a situation where many requests had the same kind of response; e.g. `DeleteFile` and `DeletePerson` might both have `DeletionResult` as their response type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way is to use an existential type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
import Control.Applicative
import Text.Read

data ARequest where
    ARequest :: Request a b => a -> ARequest
```

You would then write a parser (which would be sort of non-modular in that it would have to know about all the instances of `Request` that you care about and be able to parse them all), and the responder would be implementable in terms of existing methods:

```
parse :: [String] -> Maybe ARequest
parse ["stats"]        = ARequest <$> pure   GetSomeStatsRequest
parse ["delete", file] = ARequest <$> liftA  DeleteImportantFileRequest (parseFileName file)
parse ["sum", a, b]    = ARequest <$> liftA2 CalcSumOfNumbersRequest (readMaybe a) (readMaybe b)
parse _ = empty

respond :: ARequest -> IO String
respond (ARequest r) = serializeResponse <$> processRequest r
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems like exactly what I needed... Especially "existential type" word combination to google :) I took your approach a bit further and made it modal. In case if someone will find this question and will be interested in the resulting code, here it is (finally compiling!): https://gist.github.com/anonymous/382e2c0411dce97b6040

Comment: @SergeyMitskevich The issue with this, and [a common issue with existentials](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/), is the existentials aren't helping much.  From your gist, `SomeResponse` is basically the same thing as a string, and `SomeRequest` is basically the same thing as `(String, IO String)`. When I crack open `SomeRequest` almost the only thing I can do with what's inside is apply `processRequest`, and almost the only thing I can do to the result of *that* is apply `serializeResponse`.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what is needed in this case? This way we ensure, that if we don't know which request is parsed, we can't do anything with it, and if we know, then we know the response type as well (the compiler knows). Module may not even export `SomeRequest` constructor at all, so no pattern matching can be done... Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Probably the most elegant way of solving this problem is [servant](https://haskell-servant.github.io/).  If servant applies to your situation, you should just use it.  If not, the core idea in servant is easy to copy.  Frankly, the route you started down is roughly in this direction, and it would eventually lead to this place if taken aggressively enough.  There are a couple of issues with it currently.

The first issue is it's more important to capture `deserializeAnyRequest` in a type class than to capture `serializeResponse` in a type class.  If I have a function `A -> B`, it's much easier for me to make that into `A -> String`, discarding type information, given that I know exactly what `B` is, than to turn it into `String -> B` which requires recovering type information.  The trick is instead of looking at the data to find out what to do, we decide what to do (based on type) and then look at the data to verify that it's what we *expect*.  This is how `read`, and,  less trivially, `printf` and servant work.  So make a type class for deserialization similar to `Read`.

The next issue is modularity.  As you noticed, if we're going to drive our code by type, at some point we're going to need a type to describe all our input.  We don't want to declare some giant type for this, at least not all at once.  The solution is straightforward and simple: we make a type combinator to combine two types, and then we merely need to combine deserializers somehow and dispatch on the combined result.  At a basic level, `Either` works perfectly fine for this.

Below is a very minimalistic code example illustrating the ideas above. I didn't include an equivalent to `serializeResponse`, as it's not necessary, but there's nothing wrong with keeping it.  The deserializers are just `String -> Maybe a` functions.  This is simple but inefficient.  You could readily provide more information at the type level or return a less opaque type that would allow deserializers to be combined efficiently.  See servant, for example.  The only thing that needs to change to add a new request type (beyond writing the new code) is `AppType`, and that type can be a combination of type synonyms for subsets of the interface.  Note that this approach doesn't *preclude* you from using a less typed (and more flexible) approach that, e.g., allows adding to request handlers at run-time.  You just have a `GenericRequest` type.

You may also want to look at the [finally, tagless approach](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/) for a more structured way of handling the request types.

```
module Main where

class Deserialize a where
    deserialize :: String -> Maybe a

class DoSomething a where
    doSomething :: a -> IO ()

data RequestA = RequestA Int deriving (Read)
instance Deserialize RequestA where
    deserialize s = case reads s of [(a,_)] -> Just a; _ -> Nothing
instance DoSomething RequestA where
    doSomething (RequestA i) = print i

data RequestB = RequestB Bool Bool deriving (Read)
instance Deserialize RequestB where
    deserialize s = case reads s of [(a,_)] -> Just a; _ -> Nothing
instance DoSomething RequestB where
    doSomething (RequestB a b) = print (a && b)

instance (Deserialize a, Deserialize b) => Deserialize (Either a b) where
    deserialize s = case deserialize s of
                        Just a -> Just (Left a)
                        Nothing -> case deserialize s of
                                        Just b -> Just (Right b)
                                        Nothing -> Nothing

instance (DoSomething a, DoSomething b) => DoSomething (Either a b) where
    doSomething (Left a) = doSomething a
    doSomething (Right b) = doSomething b

type AppType = Either RequestA RequestB

main = do
    i <- getLine
    case deserialize i :: Maybe AppType of
        Just a -> doSomething a
        Nothing -> putStrLn "Bad Input"
```

I should emphasize that this is *really* minimalistic.  More realistically you'll probably want more context provided, most likely via a monad.  For example, if you did want to do that `GenericRequest` thing, you'd probably want to have the deserializer initialized from a map of request handlers, but there is no way to provide that to the `deserialize` function.  `deserialize` returning its result in a monad or taking an extra "context" parameter (which is a special case of the former) would enable that.

Comment: Thank you for detailed and well-considered response. Servant library doesn't fit my case exactly (I'm implementing hardware-level communication protocol), but I'll certainly will take a detailed look in its implementation. I have accepted Daniel's answer because I can apply it to the described problem more easily, but I definitely got XP from yours. Here is what I came up with for now (please let me know if you see any obvious mistakes in it): https://gist.github.com/anonymous/382e2c0411dce97b6040

Answer (score 1):

How about having, for each request/response pair, a function like:

```
type SerializedRequest = String

type SerializedResponse = String

parseSerializedRequest :: SerializedRequest -> Maybe (IO SerializedResponse)
```

The actual request/response types hide behind the function. We would have a list of these functions, assembled from each of your modules.

Whenever a serialized request arrives, we try each function in sequence until we find a match. The match returns the `IO` action to perform, along with the serialized response. If more than one action were possible, we can return them in a record.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that in the end we'll have `processAnyRequest :: String -> Maybe (IO String)` function that will try all those? What if user will call that function, giving DeleteFileRequest, but expecting RenameFileResponse (wrongly, but in the end both of those will be Strings)? Run-time error? Is there a way to prevent this during compilation? Also, there will be hundreds of requests, this function will, basically duplicate list of all parse functions. What if some programmer on this project will add new request, but forget to add a line in this function? Run-time error, again?

Comment: "giving DeleteFileRequest, but expecting RenameFileResponse" Perhaps the client should not decide what response type to deserialize for each request, instead having a family of `ParticularRequest -> IO ParticularResponse` functions that handle the remote call and response deserialization for him.

Comment: Please ignore the first point then, I had in mind situation like in @Carsten comment. Ok, but what if we now want a function `processAnyRequestAndPrettyPrintItToLog` ? I mean it just as an example. We may need to do something with the request information (not serialized request, but actual data), we can't lose it. Should we write a separate function for each case and list all our separate `parseSerializedRequest` methods in each?

Comment: Perhaps `parseSerializedRequest` could return a record with an additional field, an `IO` action that pretty-printed the request. In this approach, we are forced to anticipate all required operations on requests/responses, to provide a common interface.